# What is a GRCAR matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What's a `grcar` matrix?

I ran across the term while reading, and I can't find good information about it. Googling is not helping me.

Edit: came across this, can it be dumbed down?

> An n×n Grcar matrix of order k is a banded Toeplitz matrix with its
>   subdiagonal set to −1 and both its main and k superdiagonals set to 1.
>   It is a highly non-normal matrix whose pseudospectra is regularly
>   visualized.

Comment: Any context? ${}{}{}$

Comment: Added some info I found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a test matrix named after *Joseph Grcar*. It is used to test how some algorithms for eigen-decomposition perform. You may find some relevant information from the following links:

- [MVMGRC: Grcar Matrix](http://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/data/NEP/mvmgrc/mvmgrc.html)
- [Pseudospectra of Toeplitz Matrices and Operators: Banded Matrices](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/pseudospectra/toeplitz/banded.html)